# What timezone is the time part of the DateTime string along with an offset represents?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have DateTime string as `2020-01-21T16:17:01.2202038-05:00`, I would like to know `16:17:01.2202038` represents the local time or UTC time?
How can I preserve the local time in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offset is `-05:00`, which indicates that the date and time given (`2020-01-21T16:17:01.2202038`) are 5 hours behind UTC.  In other words, it is the **local time** of some time zone that is UTC-5 at that point in time.

This is not necessarily the same as the local time of the computer where you are evaluating the code, nor is the offset guaranteed to be the same for other points in time for the same time zone.

In .NET, you're much better off representing such data with the `DateTimeOffset` type, rather than the `DateTime` type.

By the way, this format is defined as part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) specifications.

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime value *does not have TZ offset data*. It has a flag for “local” or “UTC” (or unspecified). See the DateTime.Kind property. Internally the actual *value* of the DateTime is an offset from UTC, stored independently of the Kind.

If a (non-0) TZ is *displayed* when a DateTime is converted to a string, *the DateTime represents the local TZ offset and **the TZ-local time***.

*This TZ offset is calculated on-the-fly depending on the actual DateTime value and current computer (really thread) settings*. For example, it will change offsets “automatically” depending if the date is in Standard or Daylight time.* Since the calculation is done with limited data (ticks from UTC and a flag) the TZ is not necessarily “honest” across TZ shifts: *the absolute time in UTC is correct, but the currently emitted TZ offset can change as it is computed on currently
active settings*.

*Historical offsets can be inaccurate if these rules have changed multiple times, as implementations usually only store so much history.